# How to customize the order of leaf labels in a dendrogram plot?

Tags: plotting, sorting, customization, cluster-analysis

Take the following simple case as an example:

```
Needs["HierarchicalClustering`"]
SeedRandom[99];
Sort@RandomInteger[99, {10}]
```

gives

> {2, 7, 22, 34, 42, 58, 60, 62, 89, 95}

Let:

```
data = Permutations@{2, 7, 22, 34, 42, 58, 60, 62, 89, 95};
```

Then:

```
DendrogramPlot[#, LeafLabels -> #] &@data[[3628800]]
DendrogramPlot[#, LeafLabels -> #] &@data[[188999]]
DendrogramPlot[#, LeafLabels -> #] &@data[[1502634]]
```

gives:

[image]
[image]
[image]

respectively with warning message:

> Agglomerate::ties: 1 ties have been detected; reordering input may produce a different result. >>

The order of the dendrogram leafs are different.

How to customize the order of dendrogram leafs? Is there any rule or relationship between the order of the inputs and the outputs' leaf order for `DendrogramPlot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe *Mathematica* allows you to specify the leaf order aside from rearranging your data. The Hierarchical Clustering package is not as fully flexible as the native functions.

The three dendrograms above are all the same if you look at the relationships between leaves. In a dendrogram, at each split, it doesn't make a difference which group is on the left or which on is on the right.

If you were to look at R and use the `hclust` function, it always puts the most tightly grouped cluster on the left. If you need a specific order, you could export your data to R and there is an order function for the dendrogram which allows you to specify the order of leaves. Otherwise just play with data permutation until you get the dendrogram you want.

Comment: N.B. there's also RLink...